# autocompleteextender on IE is missing a list item

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two autocomplete extenders on the aspx page.

```
<div class="wrapper left">
        <div class="col214 left label">
            Location Name
        </div>
        <div class="col234 left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocationName" CssClass="col225 tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <loc:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod = "getLocationDetails" MinimumPrefixLength="4" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" 
            TargetControlID="txtLocationName" ID="AutoCompleteLocation" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" DelimiterCharacters="," ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" ></loc:AutoCompleteExtender>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="wrapper left">
        <div class="col214 left label">
            Clinician Surname
        </div>
        <div class="col234 left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClinicianSurname" CssClass="col225 tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <sur:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="getClinicianDetails" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" 
         TargetControlID="txtClinicianSurname" ID="AutoCompletSurname" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" DelimiterCharacters="," ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" ></sur:AutoCompleteExtender>
        </div>
    </div>
```

They are working fine on my localhost when displaying the list items. Once I deployed onto test environment, the list items displayed on the chrome browser are fine, but on the IE, the second list item is missing due to the textbox below it at the position of second list item. The second textbox is appearing in place of the second list item of the first textbox autocompleteextender. In the image attached, list item 'test 2' is missing on IE,however second textbox is appearing in place of it.  Could anyone please help.

Thanks  in advance.
[images of chrome and IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUOBR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have got it resolved by writing the following in web.config.
This is being incompatibility of IE 11 on the deployed version on IIS7

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

This is working fine on my machine. But once I deployed on to live, it is not working on some machines. When I press F12, the error it's coming up with is 'jquery not defined'. The auto populate text box is working fine, but there are two jquery date calendars on the page which are not working and the user unable to submit the page. 
With the above code in config, it is working fine on some machines but not on others(they cannot get the date calendar displayed and cannot submit). If I delete the above code, it's working fine on some machines but not on others (they cannot see the second listed item on auto populate text box)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to caching issue. Delete the temp files and browsing history and it's back up and running with the below code in web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```